# how to find ALL occurrences of a string in PowerPoint with the VBA replace function

Tags: vba, replace, powerpoint

I am trying to replace all carriage returns with the ¶ symbol to make the carriage returns visible in PPT (only word has a button for this, PPT does not). Since the "replace" function only finds the first occurrence, I need to loop through each string to find the next occurrences.

I am using the sample code from the MS "replace" function, but the code only finds SOME of the carriage returns but not ALL of them. What am I missing?
Thanks!

VBA code:

```
If .HasTextFrame Then
    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
        'MsgBox (.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
        Set oTxtRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange

        'Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng
        Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=Chr$(13), _
        Replacewhat:=("¶"))

        Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing
            Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters(oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length + 1, _
            oTxtRng.Length)
            charCount = charCount + 1

            'MsgBox (oTxtRng.Text)

            Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=Chr$(13), Replacewhat:=("¶"))
        Loop

    End If
End If
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find and replace a string in powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555956/how-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-powerpoint-using-vba)

Answer (score 1):

PPT uses different line ending characters, depending on version and what type of text box it is even within one version; paragraph endings are different from linebreaks also.  This page on my PPTFAQ site should help:

Paragraph endings and line breaks
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm

Comment: this did not solve my problem. I am aware of the different characters. The problem here is that I am using the "replace" function and PPT finds SOME of the line break characters but not OTHERS and it seems to be somewhat random WHICH line breaks it find.

Comment: Have you modified your example code in light of what's on the page I linked to?  If so, please edit it above so we're all talking about the same thing. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with the Microsoft Sample code.  It seems to miss certain occurrences (although consistently).  Anyway, to fix it, instead of redefining oTxtRng, I instead changed it to use the After:= parameter.  That seems to work reliably:

```
If .HasTextFrame Then
  If .TextFrame.HasText Then
    'MsgBox (.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
    Set oTxtRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange

    'Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng
    Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=Chr$(13), _
    Replacewhat:=("¶"))

    Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing
        charCount = charCount + 1

        'MsgBox (oTxtRng.Text)

        Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=Chr$(13), Replacewhat:=("¶"), After:=oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length)
    Loop

  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Replace function, not the text range Replace method, eg

```
dim sText = Replace(oTxtRng.Text, Chr$(13), "¶")

oTxtRng.Text = sText
```

Replace function replaces all occurrences in one go.

Comment: dim sText = Replace(oTxtRng.Text, Chr$(13), "¶")
does not work. PPT does not like this notation. I'm on PPT 2013
I would love to get this to work.

Comment: I am still interested in the answer to this question. when I use your suggestion I get a compile error: Expected: End of statement (with the highlight on the = before the replace

Comment: That should be in two lines:  Dim sText as String then sText = Replace(oTxtRng.Text, Chr$(13), "¶")